# How can I return true in COBOL

Tags: boolean, cobol

So I am making a program that checks if a number is divisible by another number or not. If it is its supposed to return true, otherwise false. Here's what I have so far.

P.S : I'm using `IBM (GnuCOBOL v2.2 -std=ibm-strict -O2)` to run this.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. CHECKER.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 BASE           PIC 9(5).
       01 FACTOR         PIC 9(2).
       01 RESULT     PIC 9(5).
            88 TRU  VALUE 0 .
            88 FAL  VALUE 1 THRU 99 .
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       CHECK-FOR-FACTOR SECTION.
            IF FUNCTION MOD(BASE, FACTOR) = 0 THEN
                  SET TRU TO TRUE
            ELSE
                  SET FAL TO TRUE
            END-IF.
       END PROGRAM CHECKER.
```

It gives me error saying invalid use of `level 88`. I'm sure I'm making a mistake, and I've searched for couple of days and I can't seem to find anything that can help me with it. Any ideas if it is possible in COBOL or does COBOL handle all the boolean stuff some other way ?

(Kindly do not reply with look up level 88 or some other stuff like that, I have already looked them up and they haven't been helping)

Comment: You can't SET an 88 value.  You can set another variable, like RESULT to TRU or FAL.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : I set result to tru, but it still doesnt work and gives the same error ?

Comment: Your program is totally fine, there is no problem with `SET conditional-name TO TRUE` (but it will always `MOVE` the 1st specified `VALUE` into the assigned variable - so `RESULT` will be either `0` or `1` in this case). If GC 2.2 can't handle that code then that would be a bad bug (I haven't heard of a bug like this), GC 3.x compiles that fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return `TRUE` from a program you'd need an implementation that has boolean `USAGE`, define that in `LINKAGE` and specify it in `PROCEDURE-DIVISION RETURNING true-item` and also use `CALL 'yourprog' RETURNING true-item`.

Your specified environment GnuCOBOL doesn't have a boolean `USAGE` in 2021 and can't handle `RETURNING` phrase of `PROCEDURE DIVISION` in programs.

But you can use a very common extension to COBOL which is available in both IBM and GnuCOBOL:

Before the program ends `MOVE RESULT TO RETURN-CODE` (which is a global register) and in the calling program check its value (and reset it to zero).
Then it is only up to you what value means "true" (in your program it is `0`).

As an alternative you *could* create a user-define function (`FUNCTION-ID` instead of `PROGRAM-ID` and use the `RETURNING` phrase to pass your result) - but that would mean you need to use `IF FUNCTION` instead of `CALL` + `IF RETURN-CODE` in each caller.

Comment: Thanks, will look into all of these.